# PDFsharp draws text under graphics

Tags: c#, text, graphics, z-index, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to generate a PDF document from scratch. I am trying to write text on top of a gradient filled rectangle. After generating the document, the gradient appears on top of the text rendering the text completely hidden.

```
using (var document = new PdfDocument())
{
    var page = document.AddPage();
    var graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append);
    graphics.SmoothingMode = XSmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    var bounds = new XRect(graphics.PageOrigin, graphics.PageSize);
    graphics.DrawRectangle(
        new XLinearGradientBrush(
            bounds,
            XColor.FromKnownColor(XKnownColor.Red),
            XColor.FromKnownColor(XKnownColor.White),
            XLinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal),
        bounds);
    graphics.DrawString(
        "Hello World!",
        new XFont("Arial", 20),
        XBrushes.Black,
        bounds.Center,
        XStringFormats.Center);

    document.Save("test.pdf");
    document.Close();
}
```

How can I make the text render on top of the rectangle?

I find that any images I draw later will appear on top of the rectangle.  It’s only text that hides behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
using (var document = new PdfDocument())
{
    var page = document.AddPage();
    var graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append);
    graphics.SmoothingMode = XSmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    var bounds = new XRect(graphics.PageOrigin, graphics.PageSize);
    var state = graphics.Save();
    graphics.DrawRectangle(
        new XLinearGradientBrush(
            bounds,
            XColor.FromKnownColor(XKnownColor.Red),
            XColor.FromKnownColor(XKnownColor.White),
            XLinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal),
        bounds);
    graphics.Restore(state);
    graphics.DrawString(
        "Hello World!",
        new XFont("Arial", 20),
        XBrushes.Black,
        bounds.Center,
        XStringFormats.Center);

    document.Save("test.pdf");
    document.Close();
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a bug in the library's code according to [this forum post](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=878).
The workaround is to `Save` and `Restore` the `XGraphics` object's state between operations.

Comment: Awesome!  That also fixes an issue I was having with the alpha channel sticking. Thanks!

Comment: The workaround is not needed when using the current version of PDFsharp (1.50, released last year). Those who want to stick to version 1.3x have to use the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The code given in the first post works fine when using the current version of PDFsharp, 1.50.

The workaround given in the previous answer is needed when PDFsharp version 1.3x or earlier is used.

Comment: Awesome! When recreating the sample I just used the following nuget package which I believed is the latest: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/

Comment: Add the top of the NuGet page is a note that there are newer versions and at the bottom of the page is a list with details.

Comment: Is v1.50 in beta?  Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager shows 1.32.2602 as the latest stable release, published 16-Feb-2012.

Comment: PDFsharp 1.50 is currently listed as "beta", it is the best PDFsharp you can get, it is the PDFsharp we use in our production releases.