# PdfSharp Writing text on top of a rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

I am trying to make a list of products with a quantity and a unit. Every second line should be colored light gray.

I am currently doing it in a for loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < OrderList.Count; i++)
    {
        double lineY = lineHeight * (i + 1);
        if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            XSolidBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColors.LightGray);

            graph.DrawRectangle(brush, marginLeft, lineY - 2, size.Width - marginLeft - marginRight, lineHeight - 2);

        }
        var state = graph.Save();

        graph.DrawString(
            OrderList[i].Product.Name,
            fontParagraph,
            XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(nameX, marginTop + lineY, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point),
            XStringFormats.TopLeft);

        graph.DrawString(
            OrderList[i].Quantity.ToString(),
            fontParagraph,
            XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(quantityX, marginTop + lineY, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point),
            XStringFormats.TopLeft);

        graph.DrawString(
            OrderList[i].Unit,
            fontParagraph,
            XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(unitX, marginTop + lineY, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point),
            XStringFormats.TopLeft);

        graph.Restore(state);
    }
pdf.Save("C:\\Users\\Tobias\\Desktop\\firstpage.pdf");
```

The above code was what I got from [PDFsharp draws text under graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935268/pdfsharp-draws-text-under-graphics) and
[the linked forum post in the answer](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=878)

Now, however, that doesn't work. All the gray lines are still hiding all the text.
I have the latest prerelease of PdfSharp from NuGet (1.50.4619-beta4c), and even though the answer says that it's not necessary to save the state, it doesn't work either when I omit saving the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't seem to replicate your issue.  I am also using PdfSharp from NuGet (1.50.4619-beta4c). I created a WPF test program with settings for lineHeight, marginLeft, etc:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PdfDocument document;
    private double lineHeight = 20;
    private XFont fontParagraph = new XFont("Verdana", 12, XFontStyle.Regular);
    private int marginLeft = 20;
    private int marginRight = 20;
    private int marginTop = 20;
    private int nameX = 0;
    private int quantityX = 100;
    private int unitX = 200;
    private string filename = @"C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\Orders.pdf";
    XSolidBrush TextBackgroundBrush = new XSolidBrush(XColors.LightGray);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        document = new PdfDocument();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var OrderList = new List<Order>();
        OrderList.Add(new Order {
            Unit = "L",
            Quantity = 100,
            Product = new Product { Name = "Coca Cola" }
        });
        OrderList.Add(new Order
        {
            Unit = "L",
            Quantity = 50,
            Product = new Product { Name = "Coca Cola Zero" }
        });

        PdfPage pdfPage = document.AddPage();

        XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);


        for (int i = 0; i < OrderList.Count; i++)
        {
            double lineY = lineHeight * (i + 1);
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                graph.DrawRectangle(TextBackgroundBrush, marginLeft, lineY - 2 + marginTop, pdfPage.Width - marginLeft - marginRight, lineHeight - 2);
            }

            graph.DrawString(
                OrderList[i].Product.Name,
                fontParagraph,
                XBrushes.Black,
                new XRect(nameX + marginLeft, marginTop + lineY, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point),
                XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            graph.DrawString(
                OrderList[i].Quantity.ToString(),
                fontParagraph,
                XBrushes.Black,
                new XRect(quantityX + marginLeft, marginTop + lineY, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point),
                XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            graph.DrawString(
                OrderList[i].Unit,
                fontParagraph,
                XBrushes.Black,
                new XRect(unitX + marginLeft, marginTop + lineY, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point),
                XStringFormats.TopLeft);

        }
        document.Save(filename);
        Process.Start(filename);
    }

    private class Order
    {
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    private class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My MainWindow XAML is just a button:

`<Button Width="100" Height="30" Click="Button_Click">Create PDF</Button>`

And I get the PDF as desired
[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUMLy.png).

My best suggestion to solve your issue is to play around with the settings such as lineHeight.

Comment: Your solution works, and the difference lies in this line:

`graph.DrawRectangle(TextBackgroundBrush, marginLeft, lineY - 2 + marginTop, pdfPage.Width - marginLeft - marginRight, lineHeight - 2);`

Here you add the marginTop - something I forgot. So in my code, I cover the line above it.
Thank you.